# Condicional com datas não é analisado pelo operador else?

Tags: php

Possuo a seguinte situação, um método que calcula a diferença entre as batidas de um ponto e a soma de intervalos que o colaborador realiza durante sua jornada de trabalho:

```
    //calcula as diferenças das batidas do ponto diário do colaborador
    $d1 = gmdate('H:i', strtotime('2021-08-06 15:00') - strtotime('2021-08-06 12:00')); 
    $d2 = gmdate('H:i', strtotime('2021-08-06 15:30') - strtotime('2021-08-06 15:00')); 
    $d3 = gmdate('H:i', strtotime('2021-08-06 17:00') - strtotime('2021-08-06 15:30')); 
    $d4 = gmdate('H:i', strtotime('2021-08-06 17:30') - strtotime('2021-08-06 17:00')); 
    $d5 = gmdate('H:i', strtotime('2021-08-06 21:00') - strtotime('2021-08-06 17:30')); 
    
    //subtotal: soma dos horários trabalhados

    $minutos = date("i", strtotime($d3));
    $hora = date("H", strtotime($d3));

    $subtotal = strtotime("+$minutos minutes", strtotime($d1));
    $subtotal = strtotime("+$hora hours", $subtotal);


    $minutos = date("i", strtotime($d5));
    $hora = date("H", strtotime($d5));

    $subtotal = strtotime("+$minutos minutes", $subtotal);
    $subtotal = strtotime("+$hora hours", $subtotal);

    //intervalo: soma de dos intervalos realilizados

    $minutos = date("i", strtotime($d4));
    $hora = date("H", strtotime($d4));

    $interval = strtotime("+$minutos minutes", strtotime($d2));
    $interval = strtotime("+$hora hours", $interval);

    //calculo p/ horas a mais ou devendo
    if (strtotime($subtotal) >= strtotime("08:00")) {
        $extra = strtotime("-8 hours", $subtotal);
    } else {
        //N CAI AQUI!!!
    }

    $data = [
        'd1' => $d1,
        'd2' => $d2,
        'd3' => $d3,
        'd4' => $d4,
        'd5' => $d5,        
        'subtotal' => "Subtotal: " . date("H:i", $subtotal),
        'intervalo' => "Intervalo: " .  date("H:i", $interval),
        'extra' => "Extra: " . date("H:i", $extra)
    ];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo  '</pre>';
```

Acontece que na minha condicional, caso o colaborador tenha um subtotal de 07:50, este não chega a ser analisado pelo operador `else`.
Não sei o que esta errado.
Aceito também recomendações em relação a um código mais limpo.

Comment: Qual é o valor de `$subtotal` quando não entra no Else?

Comment: No código que eu postei o subtotal é 08:00 até aí tudo bem, mas tu precisas colocar um entrada do colaborador em atraso, como por exemplo a chegada dele na empresa as 12:10, logo o subtotal será 07:50 aí que não entra no else!

Comment: Por favor, veja como fazer um [mcve], não adianta abrir uma pergunta apontando um erro e dar um exemplo que funciona como era esperado. É tipo ir no médico quando está saudável e dizer "agora estou bem, mas faz a consulta aí para quando eu ficar mal eu já saber o que tenho".

Comment: Meu palpite é que deveria ser `if ($subtotal >= strtotime("08:00"))`, pois `$subtotal` já é o retorno de `strtotime`, então não faz sentido passá-lo novamente para a mesma função (fiz uns testes aqui e vi que o PHP converte o valor dele para string e faz coisas bem estranhas, faça um debug e veja o valor retornado por `strtotime($subtotal)`). De qualquer forma, o PHP não tem uma forma nativa decente de trabalhar com durações (e nem com datas, se quer saber :-D), mas da forma que foi feito, acho que está complicando demais...

Comment: Datas e durações são coisas diferentes (uma data/hora é um momento específico, uma duração é uma quantidade de tempo): `strtotime` e `gmdate` trabalham bem com datas, mas não com durações (se passar de 24 horas dá problema, para valores menores "funciona" por coincidência). Dê uma olhada [aqui](/a/401064/112052), [aqui](/a/519091/112052), [aqui](/a/417271/112052) e [aqui](/a/407406/112052) para entender melhor e ter algumas alternativas sobre como fazer esses cálculos.

Comment: Obrigado @Woss pela colaboração, mas foi na correria, pretendo me adaptar melhor em relação as minhas questões publicadas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não cai no else por que o valor do subtotal é 8h, então ele é igual ou maior que o 8h.

```
    Array
(
    [d1] => 03:00
    [d2] => 00:30
    [d3] => 01:30
    [d4] => 00:30
    [d5] => 03:30
    [subtotal] => Subtotal: 08:00
    [intervalo] => Intervalo: 01:00
    [extra] => Extra: 00:00
)
```

Basta troca o resultado do

```
$minutos = date("i", strtotime($d5));
$hora = date("H", strtotime($d5));
```

para

```
$minutos = date("i", strtotime($d5));
$hora = date("H", strtotime($d4));
```

que o subtotal vai diminuir e vai cair no else

Comment: Na verdade a dinâmica é que ao colocar a entrada por exemplo em atraso no $d1: uma batida as 12:10 quer dizer que o colaborador fez um total de 07:50, logo teria que entrar no else, ve aí testa assim pra ver!